# Transfer files from ubuntu to window 8 or 7 using vsftpd

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to transfer files from Ubuntu 14.04 to Windows 8. I have installed and configured vsftpd on my virtual machine vmware. When I login to my windows trough ftp, it gives incorrect password even though my root password is right.

```
adeel@ubuntu:~$ sudo service vsftpd restart
[sudo] password for adeel: 
vsftpd start/running, process 8676
adeel@ubuntu:~$ hostname
ubuntu
adeel@ubuntu:~$ ftp adeel
Connected to adeel.localdomain.
220 Microsoft FTP Service

//now i am connecting ftp to windows 8 but it is giving incorrect password.
Name (adeel:adeel): adeel
331 Password required
Password:
530-User cannot log in.
Win32 error:   The user name or password is incorrect. 
Error details: An error occurred during the authentication process.
530 End
Login failed.
Remote system type is Windows_NT.
ftp>
```

Comment: It seems to me you are trying to connect *from* Ubuntu *to* Windows 8 via ftp? In this case you need a running ftp server on Windows 8, whereas I think you have a running ftp server on Ubuntu (vsftpd). Please confirm or correct...

Comment: yes i have ftp only at ubuntu not on windows

Comment: so why use ftp to connect to Windows?

Comment: because my instructor gave me the project of transferring files from ubuntu to windows using ftp.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not convinced that using ftp is the best way to do, but to answer your question: you need to set up an ftp server on your Windows machine. This is a palaver but extensive instructions are available [here](http://www.sysprobs.com/step-by-step-guide-how-to-setup-ftp-server-on-windows-8). Sorry just to link but there are too many steps to be worth reproducing here.

You might consider other ways of connecting, such as creating a Windows share on your Win8 machine and then accessing this from Ubuntu (uses Samba) - some info [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/176471/how-to-share-files-between-windows-and-linux/) - I think this would be easier.

Either way keep security in mind: beware of leaving shares open or of leaving an ftp server running unless you are sure you know what you are doing.

Comment: Oh and you don't need vsftpd to send files if you are running the operation from the Ubuntu machine, on this machine you just need an ftp client such as FileZilla (gui) or lftp (command line).